# assign the value of html textbox to title of div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

line 1:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" /><input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
```

line 2:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=#msdhoni">#msdhoni</a>
<div class="twitStream 5" id="tweets" title="#msdhoni" >
```

What I want- when a user input some thing in text box (in line 1) that should become the title of the div (in line 2) on click of the botton (in line 1). Actually want to replace #msdhoni everywhere in code with the text input in the textbox.

Jquery code I m using:(Please suggest the change in this code to make this possible)

```
String.prototype.linkify=function(){
return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&;\?\/.=]+/g,function(m){
return m.link(m);
});
};
String.prototype.linkuser=function(){
return this.replace(/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g,function(u){
return u.link("http://twitter.com/"+u.replace("@",""));
});
};
String.prototype.linktag=function(){
return this.replace(/[]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/,function(t){
return t;
});
};

var showTweetLinks='none';
function fetch_tweets(elem){
elem = $(elem);

keyword = escape(elem.attr('title'));


num=elem.attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1);

var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" +keyword+ "&rpp=" + num +            "&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
$(json.results).each(function(){
    var tTime=new Date(Date.parse(this.created_at));
    var cTime=new Date();
    var sinceMin=Math.round((cTime-tTime)/60000);
    if(sinceMin==0){
        var sinceSec=Math.round((cTime-tTime)/1000);
        if(sinceSec<10)
            var since='less than 10 seconds ago';
        else if(sinceSec<20)
            var since='less than 20 seconds ago';
        else
            var since='half a minute ago';
    }
    else if(sinceMin==1){
        var sinceSec=Math.round((cTime-tTime)/1000);
        if(sinceSec==30)
            var since='half a minute ago';
        else if(sinceSec<60)
            var since='less than a minute ago';
        else
            var since='1 minute ago';
    }
    else if(sinceMin<45)
        var since=sinceMin+' minutes ago';
    else if(sinceMin>44&&sinceMin<60)
        var since='about 1 hour ago';
    else if(sinceMin<1440){
        var sinceHr=Math.round(sinceMin/60);
        if(sinceHr==1)
            var since='about 1 hour ago';
        else
            var since='about '+sinceHr+' hours ago';
    }
    else if(sinceMin>1439&&sinceMin<2880)
        var since='1 day ago';
    else{
        var sinceDay=Math.round(sinceMin/1440);
        var since=sinceDay+' days ago';
    }
    var tweetBy='<a class="tweet-user" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/'+this.from_user+'">@'+this.from_user+'</a> <span class="tweet-time">'+since+'</span>';
    if(showTweetLinks.indexOf('reply')!=-1)
        tweetBy=tweetBy+' &middot; <a class="tweet-reply" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/?status=@'+this.from_user+' &in_reply_to_status_id='+this.id+'&in_reply_to='+this.from_user+'">Reply</a>';
    if(showTweetLinks.indexOf('view')!=-1)
        tweetBy=tweetBy+' &middot; <a class="tweet-view" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/'+this.from_user+'/statuses/'+this.id+'">View Tweet</a>';
    if(showTweetLinks.indexOf('rt')!=-1)
        tweetBy=tweetBy+' &middot; <a class="tweet-rt" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/?status=RT @'+this.from_user+' '+escape(this.text.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'))+'&in_reply_to_status_id='+this.id+'&in_reply_to='+this.from_user+'">RT</a>';
    var tweet='<div class="tweet"><div class="tweet-left"><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/'+this.from_user+'"><img width="48" height="48" alt="'+this.from_user+' on Twitter" src="'+this.profile_image_url+'" /></a></div><div class="tweet-right"><p class="text">'+this.text.linkify().linkuser().linktag().replace(/<a/g,'<a target="_blank"')+'<br />'+tweetBy+'</p></div><br style="clear: both;" /></div>';
    elem.append(tweet);
});
});
return(false);
}
$(function(){
showTweetLinks=showTweetLinks.toLowerCase();
if(showTweetLinks.indexOf('all')!=-1)
showTweetLinks='reply,view,rt';
$('.twitStream').each(function(){
fetch_tweets(this);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i understood from ur question:

```
 $(function () {
            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                $("#tweets").attr("title", $("input[id='Text1']").val());
                $.each($("input:text"), function () {
                    $(this).val($("#tweets").attr("title"));
                });
            });
        });
```

Hope this will help a bit